# Appium doctor show error, after installation of sdk as well

Tags: android, appium

Any suggestion why this issue?

```
✔ Xcode is installed at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode Command Line Tools are installed.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ DevToolsSecurity is enabled.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Authorization DB is set up properly.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: /usr/local/bin/node
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ HOME is set to: /Users/piyushkumar
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to: //Users/piyushkumar/Desktop
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ adb could NOT be found at '/Users/piyushkumar/Desktop/platform-tools/adb'!
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ android could NOT be found at '/Users/piyushkumar/Desktop/tools/android'!
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ emulator could NOT be found at '/Users/piyushkumar/Desktop/tools/emulator'!
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually the Android SDK gets installed to this location:
`/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk`

If you do have the Android SDK at your Desktop, then ANDROID_HOME should probably be set to something like this:
`/Users/piyushkumar/Desktop/sdk`

To check that you're looking at the correct directory, `ls` should give you these files:
`SDK Readme.txt add-ons/    build-tools/    extras/     platform-tools/ platforms/  sources/    system-images/  temp/       tools/`

Comment: My ls shows {Applications  Library   Public
Desktop   Movies   local
Documents  Music   node-latest-install
Downloads  Pictures}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the platform tools folder is added to your `PATH`

Comment: its already been added, How can I manually add adb,android, emulators to the path?

Comment: Not required to add it explicitly. Once you have added android_home it will cover.